# Change insert record based on hostname

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have a script that inserts test data into a database. This script is shared by different developers who all use their own s3 bucket. I have a table called s3 with `s3bucket` column and it will only have one row which is the name of their s3 bucket.

Is there a way to do a conditional insert into that table for that one record?
For example, there are 3 developers and there is s3bucket1, s3bucket2, s3bucket3.

@@hostname would not work as the ip can change.

For a single developer, the script for inserting data would include the following statement:

```
Insert into customer.s3info(s3bucket)
Values ('example_bucket_dev1)
```

Since we have multiple developers and they all use their own bucket, the statement would ideally look something like this:

```
If @@server_uuid = '111111111'
Insert into customer.s3info(s3bucket)
Values (example_bucket_dev1)

If @@server_uuid = '222222222'
Insert into customer.s3info(s3bucket)
Values (example_bucket_dev2)

If @@server_uuid = '333333333'
Insert into customer.s3info(s3bucket)
Values (example_bucket_dev3)
```

Comment: Can you provide full, but minimal, code showing what you are trying to do in the case of only one developer? And then describe how you want the behavior to change for the other developers.

Comment: @DougDeden I updated the question to include an example of what I am trying to achieve. Not sure the syntax is correct since that is my question. Thank you.